# Django - Exclude options from ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, web, frameworks

I am having a hard time trying to exclude choices from a ModelChoiceField using queryset. I am not very experienced with django and python, your help would be very appreciated.

I am trying to make a form to assign users to a project.
I use an inlineformset and I'd like to remove the users that are already assigned to this project from the user combobox in the formset.

The ModelForm:

```
class ProjectUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        project = kwargs.pop('project', None)
        super(ProjectUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if project:
            self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(project=project)

    class Meta:
    model = ProjectUser
```

The View:

```
@login_required
def project_update(request, pk):
    if pk is None:
        project = Project()
    else:
        project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)

    ProjectUserFormset = inlineformset_factory(Project, ProjectUser,
        form=ProjectUserForm(project=project),
        extra=0,
        max_num=User.objects.count(),
        fk_name='project',
        can_delete=False,
    )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        project_form = ProjectForm(
            request.POST,
            instance=project
        )
        project_user_formset = ProjectUserFormset(
            request.POST,
            instance=project,
            prefix='project_user'
        )  
        if project_form.is_valid() and project_user_formset.is_valid():
            project = project_form.save(commit=False)
            project_user_formset.save()
            project.save()

    else:
        project_form = ProjectForm(instance=project)
        project_user_formset = ProjectUserFormset(
            instance=project,
            prefix='project_user'
        )

    return render(request, "Nexquality/project_form.html", {
        'title': 'Modify project: '+project.name,
        'form': project_form,
        'project_user_formset': project_user_formset,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the formset factory isn't passing along the project instance. It only expects you to pass the form class itself, not an instance of the class. I'm surprised that's not throwing an error.

The way I handle this is to curry the instance to the form:

```
from django.utils.functional import curry

. . .
ProjectUserFormset = inlineformset_factory(Project, ProjectUser,
    form=ProjectUserForm,
    extra=0,
    max_num=User.objects.count(),
    fk_name='project',
    can_delete=False,
)
ProjectUserFormset.form = staticmethod(curry(ProjectUserForm, project=project))
```